# Member not created in live paypal mode with simple membership plugin

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

We have installed the latest Version:4.3.4 of the plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-membership/

https://simple-membership-plugin.com/membership-registration-process-overview/

We follow all the instructions in the above-mentioned link.

Sandbox testing works fine; we can create a member and user after payment is done.

However, when we try to make a payment in LIVE mode, members and users are not created, which is why we cannot display the member’s email address on the thank you page.

We also checked if any jquery or other conflict issues on the website but did not find any issues.

The simple membership plugin in already updated with the latest version.

We need to created member when place the order with paypal live mode.

So, we can set the member email address on the thank you page after payment done with paypal live mode.

Currently, member not created so we are not able to display the member email address on the thank you page after paypment.